# Open Source JSON log viewer for remote files

Tags: json, windows, logging, remote-server

I am using bunyan to log a nodejs app on my ubuntu server. As a result, I get JSON logs.

I tried to find a tool which I can run on my windows computer which connects like every 5 sec via FTP to my ubuntu server, gets the latest log lines from the log, and displays the updated log in a nice way on my windows machine.

I thought this must be really easy to find, but I found nothing.

Can anyone recommend me something useful?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/sevdokimov/log-viewer can help. You can install it on the ubuntu server, specify the path to log files in the configuration, then observe logs via Web interface.

UI will not look nice for JSON logs, but I can improve it in the next version.